# Converting these php files to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cakephp

I have these two file in my project that I am migrating from php. I have developed most of it by seeing the functionality but there are these two files which I don't know about. If somebody could have a look and help me converting these, I would really be thankful.

**Menu.ctp**

```
<?php  
Configure::write('debug', 0);  
echo($_GET['callback'].'(');  
echo ($javascript->object($profiles));  
echo(');');  
?>
```

**Retrieve.ctp**

```
<?php
Configure::write('debug', 0);
echo($_GET['callback'].'(');
echo ($javascript->object($profile));
echo(');');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

This tell application to put debug mode to off. If you in debug mode, any application error message will be displayed which is not appropiate for production or ajax call.

```
echo($_GET['callback'].'(');
```

$_GET is a global variable which hold all GET request parameter. For example, request to index.php?callback=some_callback will set $_GET['callback'] to some_callback.

```
echo ($javascript->object($profiles));
```

This is javascript helper in CakePHP which turn PHP array($profiles) into JSON.

```
echo($_GET['callback'].'(');
echo ($javascript->object($profile));
echo(');');
```

This will otuput : `callback_parameter(JSON form of profiles);`